# mkdir fails with directory exists after bash test if directory exists fails

Tags: bash

I'm building a gitlab ci pipeline, and try to create a directory if it not exists.
Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
$ if [ ! -d aws ]
$ then
$ mkdir aws
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘aws’: File exists
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

```
the relevant part of the gitlab-ci.yml

  script:
    - export
    - ls -al
    - if [ ! -d aws ]
    - then
    - mkdir aws
    - fi
```

```
$ ls -al
total 128
drwxrwxrwx 16 root root  4096 Sep 17 12:07 .
drwxrwxrwx  6 root root  4096 Sep 17 12:07 ..
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root  4096 Sep 17 12:07 aws
```

Comment: What is that you are showing? Please show you gitlab-ci.yml . Please show an [MCVE]

Comment: `-d` only test if it is a directory, it does not test if a standard file or symbolic link or any other type of file/entry exist with the name

Comment: Do you have a regular file named aws?

Comment: Can you use `if` statements in a block like that, or will it just execute line by line causing two failures and an unconditional mkdir?

Answer (score 2):

I now just used mkdir -p and removed the test

Comment: `mkdir- p` is a great time-saver. Note that you can create a whole multi-level directory path like this: `mkdir -p /path/to/new_dir1/new_dir2/new_dir3`.

Comment: This is the most concise solution and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I'd still like to know how the test returned false. If it were a one-time thing then maybe it was a race condition with another process, but even that should be really rare.  Is it at all possible there was a non-directory file that someone else cleaned up and fixed between your error message and your `ls` output?

Comment: This is YAML. `[` and `]` are metacharacters that could possibly need quotes in YAML, but if you have spaces around them on both sides it *shouldn't* be an issue... Maybe there's no space after the `]`?
c.f. https://support.asg.com/mob/mvw/10_0/mv_ag/using_quotes_with_yaml_special_characters.htm

Answer (score 1):

you have something with `aws` name, which might be symbolic link, hard link, regular file, vs.

first delete or move that file to somewhere else then try again

Comment: $ ls -al
total 128
drwxrwxrwx 16 root root  4096 Sep 17 12:07 .
drwxrwxrwx  6 root root  4096 Sep 17 12:07 ..
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root  4096 Sep 17 12:07 aws

Comment: need `ls -ld aws`

Answer (score 0):

you can try `-e` (returns true if file exists regardless of type).